# Lightning: How to get attributes json from component reference?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I extract component which is used as template and I'd like to build multiple components dynamically based on this template component. How I can extract json of attribute values in order to pass this json as componentConfig for dynamic components?:

```
$A.componentService.newComponentAsync(
    this,
    function(message) {
        var div1 = cmp.find("div1");
        // Replace existing body with the dynamic component
        div1.set("v.body", message);
    },
    componentConfig
);
```

Comment: You're asking how to clone a component?